# how to get correct time from Uidatepicker

Tags: iphone, nsdate, uidatepicker

I am using below code to get date and time from datepicker.

When i am using formatter it is giving correct time .

but when i am converting that string into `NSdate` object ,then it is not giving the correct value of time.

```
 NSDate *choice = [datepicker date];
 NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"]; 
 NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:choice]; 


NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateString]; NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

`DateString` is giving correct value but when i am converting it in to `NSdate` again it is giving wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

If the data that is being logged has some hour in difference then its ok since logging an `NSDate` will log it in `GMT` time zone, then this is not a bug, if your `dateString` is correct and your `NSdate` has some hours of difference then you have no issues

Comment: but i want the date and time which i am selected in UIdatepicker

Comment: what is the data that you get? what is the value of dateString and of date